# Why is my ReactJS component state change not triggering a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, state, rerender

I have a ReactJS class component with the following constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        // Defaults (London)
        latitude: 51.509865,
        longitude: -0.118092,
        userAddress: null
      };
      this.getCoordinates = this.getCoordinates.bind(this);
    }
```

I then attempt to get the user co-ordinates and save them to the state:

```
    // On component initialisation, get the users location in co-ordinates and set the state accordingly
    componentDidMount() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getCoordinates, this.handleLocationError);
      } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }
    
    getCoordinates(position) {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      })
    }
```

I am passing the users co-ordinates to a child function which renders a weather card on the screen with the current temperature at the users location.

Render function:

```
    render() {
      (some code)
        <div><CreateWeatherCard lat={this.state.latitude} long={this.state.longitude} /></div>
       (some code)
    }
```

The function to create the weather card takes the users co-ords as props, uses them in a POST request API call and should then display the temp at the users current location on the screen

```
function CreateWeatherCard(props) {
  const classes = cardStyles();
  let [currentTemp, setCurrentTemp] = React.useState([]);

    // console.log(props.lat)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.post('/weatheratcoords/', {
        lat: props.lat,
        long: props.long
      });
      // console.log(request);
      // console.log(request.data.currentTemp);
      setCurrentTemp(request.data.currentTemp);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

   return
     blah blah
```

But as I am running the backend locally, I can see I am only receiving one API call with the default co-ordinates from the state constructor. I am never receiving a second call with the updated co-ordinates. I know that the state is updating successfully as I can see my own lat/long co-ordinates in the component state in React dev tools.

My understanding is that a state change should trigger a re-render, which in turn should create a new API call with the correct user co-ordinates? Can somebody help me to understand why this isn't happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your `useEffect()`.

You have written it this way:

```js
 React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.post('/weatheratcoords/', {
        lat: props.lat,
        long: props.long
      });
      // console.log(request);
      // console.log(request.data.currentTemp);
      setCurrentTemp(request.data.currentTemp);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

The second parameter is empty array which means the `useEffect()` will be only executed once.

---

### Solution

As you are passing the values using props to the child component, so when props changes the `useEffect()` will be executed. For that pass props inside the array in your `useEffect()` as a second parameter.

Make it like this:

```js
 React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.post('/weatheratcoords/', {
        lat: props.lat,
        long: props.long
      });
      // console.log(request);
      // console.log(request.data.currentTemp);
      setCurrentTemp(request.data.currentTemp);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [props]);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. That solved the problem. I will do some more research on the useEffect function to ensure I am using it properly in the future! Thankyou for the concise explanation.